# RecyclerView keeps scrolling after reaching end of list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

### RecyclerView keeps scrolling

I am making a Media Library app.  When I use the recyclerview list it scrolls over the same
items again and again.  It does not stop when it reaches the bottom of the file list.

```
class MediaListAdapter(val mediaList: ArrayList<Media>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MediaListAdapter.MediaViewHolder>(){

private var context: Context? = null

fun updateMediaList(newMediaList: List<Media>){
    mediaList.clear()
    mediaList.addAll(newMediaList)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MediaViewHolder {
    context = parent.context
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ItemMediaBinding>(inflater, R.layout.item_media, parent, false)
    return MediaViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MediaViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.view.btnPlayVideo.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    holder.view.mediaItem = mediaList[position]
    if(mediaList[position].mediaUrl.contains(".mp4")){
        holder.view.btnPlayVideo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.view.btnPlayVideo.setOnClickListener {
            context!!.startActivity(Intent(context, VideoViewActivity::class.java).putExtra("videoUrl", mediaList[position].mediaUrl))
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount():Int {
    return mediaList.size
}

class MediaViewHolder(var view: ItemMediaBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view.root)
}
```

---

That is my Adapter class.
The media information is being pulled from a database containing the image urls and other information related to the information.

I have compared my code to a similar solution that works how I want and can't find any reason for the bug.

```
val media = MutableLiveData<List<Media>>()
val loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
private val mediaList = ArrayList<String>()


fun fetchFromDatabase() {
    loading.value = true
    loadImages()
    launch {
        storeMedia(mediaList)
        val media = MediaDatabase(getApplication()).mediaDao().getAllMedia()
        mediaRetrieved(media)
    }
}

private fun mediaRetrieved(mediaList: List<Media>) {
    media.value = mediaList
    loading.value = false
}

private fun storeMedia(list: List<String>) {
    var found = false
    launch {
        val dao = MediaDatabase(getApplication()).mediaDao().getAllMedia()
        for(item in list){
            found = false
            for(media in dao){
                if(item == media.mediaLocation){
                    found = true
                    break
                }
            }
            if(!found){
                val media = Media(mediaUrl = item)
                MediaDatabase(getApplication()).mediaDao().insert(media)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is the code from the viewholder were I am adding data to the recyclerview adapter

Comment: seems your adding the items again and again. Can you show the code of the activity that  is filling the adapter

Comment: Hi @HayssamSoussi I added the code above now

Answer (score 0):

Check the size of items that are available is your db/api from wherever you are retrieving media information(May be you are receiving the repeated data).